# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no cplex1290 in java.library.path

Tags: intellij-idea, libraries, cplex, clips

"
As the title suggests, I have a problem including two native libraries (CLIPSJNI and cplex.jar) in the same IntelliJ project.
I set the parameter
Djava.library.path, as shown in the respective folders of the two libraries.

[image]

Comment: What're your IDE and JDK version?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA EDU 2019.3 - JDK Java 1.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path passed to `java.library.path` should be the absolute path to the directory containing `cplex1290.dll` not `cplex.jar`. Using the paths in your screenshot, this should be:

```
java.library.path="C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community129\cplex\bin\x64_win64"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this in Intellij is:

1. Add a new library in "File -> Proejct Structure -> Libraries" with absolute path "C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community129\cplex\bin\x64_win64".
2. Intellij will ask you to specify what types of the library it is. Choose "Native Library Locations".
3. Click "Apply" in the bottom right.

In this way, you don't need to edit your "Run Configuration".